# Grails Upgrade - 1.3.7 to 2.4.1 for Java 1.8 Compatibility. How to add custom jars in classpath

Tags: grails, upgrade

I have upgraded my application from grails 1.3.7 to 2.4.1 for Java 1.8 compatibility.
While running the application I am getting `ClassNotFoundException`.

That class is present in custom jar. I tried adding below in buildConfig but that didn't help.

```
flatDir name:'myCustomjar.jar', dirs:'abc/lib'
```

Please guide me on how to add the jar in classpath for grails application.

I also tried adding the jar manually in `user.home/.grails/ivy-cache` still the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

In grails 2.4 it is sufficient to place the JAR file into `<root>/lib` folder. And then add

```
dependencies {
  compile files('libs/your_lib.jar')
}
```